# Coordinating shared state on a large-scale clustered system with dynamic responses

Tags: java, cluster-computing, state, distributed

I'm designing a poker webapp with multiple users sharing a game, and distributed across many servers. Assuming I want to maintain the state of the game in a single server - is there a way I can 'route' or 'guide' logged in users interact with the machine that is hosting the game? The game involves lots of interactive responses via AJAX, and so coordinating state in the database across multiple servers is not an option. (If your view is that this the state can be maintained across multiple servers using a distributed cache - then I'm open to that too).

To make it simpler, assume the webapp is implemented in Java.

If you could provide example libraries and information about routing in your answer that would be helpful. (Eg why or why Apache Zookeeper is an appropriate way of dealing with this problem).

Answer (score 0):

At a load balancer level, there is the concept of `sticky sessions`, supported by load balancers like HAProxy, which will ensure that the same user will always be routed to the same server (with https it may be harder).

However, it is hard to ensure that 2 users which logged to different servers finally are playing on the same server. And this also means that if the server goes down, the game is lost for both players. Perhaps you should persist the game on a distributed cache and handle failures?

As far as I understand, in HAProxy, it is possible to use the query string to route the request to the appropriate server.
http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt

But you'd better use stateless requests and be able to deal with requests from many servers.

Comment: Ok - so if we handle requests from many servers, what would you propose as the coordination mechanism for the shared state of the game in a way that facilitates rapid responses?

Comment: Ahaha there are many ways to handle this state. One of the fastest way, using Java, is to use an In Memory Datagrid. There are some free opensourced IMDB like Hazelcast. But before checking these fast technologies, have you effectively mesured that a standart DB is too slow? It is hard to answer without knowing exactly the constraints of your application